# How use Style in PageFunction?

Tags: wpf, styles

How use Style in PageFunction?

This construction is not work:

```
<PageFunction.Resources>
    <Style ... />
</PageFunction.Resources>
```

Comment: you want to style pagefunction or any control within in?

Comment: For any controls in Page